# Can't run .run files(libpng error)

Tags: software-installation, libpng

When I use the command

```
+chmod +x appname.run
```

and then

```
./appname.run
```

I get the following message, but nothing more happens:

```
libpng warning: Application jmp_buf size changed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What is `appname` - where did you get it, and how did you install it? It sounds like it is incompatible with the version of `libpng` on your system.

Comment: Pretty sure it has something to do with your fonts, check out this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1213079/736759)