# libpng warning: Application jmp_buf size changed Segmentation fault when try to run xampp installation file

Tags: 18.04, apache2, xampp

I trying to install XAMPP on my ubuntu 18.04 but I got this warning from libpng by running this command:

```
sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-7.3.9-0-installer.run
```

The thing need to be considered is that I got this warning on all versions of XAMPP. Someone already asks the same question there [libpng warning : Application jmp_buf size changed - while installing XAMPP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113215/libpng-warning-application-jmp-buf-size-changed-while-installing-xampp) but the answer is useless. Its a humble request please help.
I am not able to install XAMPP since last two days.

Answer (score 5):

Solved this by running the xampp installer with strace:

```
sudo strace -Ff -tt ./xampp-linux-x64-7.4.2-0-installer.run 2>&1 | tee strace-xampp.log
```

Opened strace-xampp.log and saw at the very end of the log that NotoColorEmoji.ttf crashed the app

```
[pid 44306] 06:00:07.874986 stat("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoColorEmoji.ttf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=7745408, ...}) = 0
[pid 44306] 06:00:07.875040 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoColorEmoji.ttf", O_RDONLY) = 23
[pid 44306] 06:00:07.875118 fcntl(23, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
[pid 44306] 06:00:07.875142 fstat(23, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=7745408, ...}) = 0
[pid 44306] 06:00:07.875183 mmap(NULL, 7745408, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 23, 0) = 0x7f2b12e49000
[pid 44306] 06:00:07.875229 close(23)   = 0
[pid 44306] 06:00:07.875325 write(2, "libpng warning: Application jmp_"..., 48libpng warning: Application jmp_buf size changed) = 48
[pid 44306] 06:00:07.875359 write(2, "\n", 1
) = 1
[pid 44306] 06:00:07.875411 --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x40} ---
[pid 44307] 06:00:07.875440 <... select resumed> <unfinished ...>) = ?
[pid 44307] 06:00:07.974988 +++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
06:00:07.975443 +++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
```

So I deleted the whole font by running

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great finding! The same works for Xilinx ISE 14.7